# OpenVZ: Is it possible to add a new ploop disk to an existing container residing on an OpenVZ host?

Tags: openvz

I have a container (Virtual Machine) running on an OpenVZ server and I would like to attach another ploop disk to this container.
The `/` mount point of the container is already configured as ploop drive and I would like to add another ploop disk of 100GB to the running container, Is it possible? if so, how is it done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try my manual: http://www.stableit.ru/2013/11/how-to-mount-multiple-disks-to-openvz.html

If you have an account in OpenVZ bugzilla please add write few words about why this feature required for you: https://bugzilla.openvz.org/show_bug.cgi?id=2754.

Comment: Thanks alot, great guide! I only needed the `ploop init` syntax.